# Random Pause HTML5 Video Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

i Cant To Do Random Pause In HTML5 Video Player . Anybody Can Help Me?

```
function vidSeek(){
var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
vid.currentTime = seekto;
var currentsec = Math.random();
if(currentsec = 3){
    vid.pause();
    console.log("STOP");
}
```

Comment: It's been a while with javascript, but `if(currentsec = 3){` ... looks odd to me. Should be `==` even in javascript, no?

Comment: Math.random() will give you a number (float) between 0 and 1... Your condition doesn't make any sense. And @Fildor is right, == is the way to go to make a comparison.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Use previous two comments to fix your code

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest you do and why:

```
function videoSeek(){
    var video = document.getElementById("IDofVideo"); //Get video player

    //stuff happens here...

    var currentsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; //Gives you # between 1 and 4.
    if(currentsec == 3){
        video.pause();
        console.log("STOP");
    }
}
```

**First,** I don't know what your variable `vid` is or how you got it so I'm showing you how I would set it.

**Second,** the random number you have should definitely be changed, like **@johnkork stated**. I don't know the range of numbers you need so I just did an example of 1-4.

**Third,** the if statement must use either `==` or `===` for comparison like **@Fildor stated**. Here is a good article explaining why **[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)**

And last, assuming `vid` was properly set and everything, your `.pause();` call should work.

I don't really see what you are trying to accomplish with this, so having a goal would help display what you need to do. Hopefully this helps.